# What are the required steps to fix 'remote certification invalid' error while logging in to Visual Studio with SSO authentication URI?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, certificate, single-sign-on

Receiving certificate error  while trying to SSO login any Microsoft Application using its authentication URI i.e. login.microsoftonline.com from browser or signing into Visual Studio.

[image: Web error]

During logging into the Visual studio, it is showing some error of "remote certification is invalid", due to which login is not possible.

[image: Visual Studio login error]

Please share the required steps or documentation to mitigate the issue

Verified the certificate, which was not expired. Given in the screen shot.